# How to get all data without getting values of the first cell with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to get data without getting the first cell's values. Moreover, how I can extend this with a selected cell to make it easier for the maintenance, ex: third cell, fifth cell, or both third and fourth cells...

**HTML:**

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td class="ms-vb2">2004</td>
            <td class="ms-vb2">1000</td>
            <td class="ms-vb2">400</td>
            <td class="ms-vb2 ms-vb-lastCell">600</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var remove_solidClass = $("td.ms-vb2.eq(0)");
        if (!remove_solidClass) {
            var arrayList1 = $("td.ms-vb2:contains('')");
            alert(arrayList1.text());
        }
```

**JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/huydq91/hDLyk/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use $("td:not(:first)")

:not()
https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

:first
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_first.asp

:nth-child() get other child
http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It works well with a half question **http://jsfiddle.net/huydq91/hDLyk/3/**. How about the half one?

Comment: `var arrayList1 = $("td.ms-vb2:contains(''):not(:nth-child(2))")
    alert(arrayList1.text());` if you want to alert all except second child.

Comment: That's great. What if when I would like to alert all except some childs which were assigned before?

Comment: uhh. I think create a custom data attribute of the element you have assigned before. then alert all element without a custom data.

Comment: Could you please give me a simple example with **JSFIDDLE**? For example with this JSFIDDLE: I would like to alert all except those elements `<td class="ms-vb2">2004</td> <td class="ms-vb2">1000</td>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[:gt()](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)** selector along with **[.map()](https://api.jquery.com/map/)**:

```
var tdArr = $('table tr td:gt(0)').map(function() {
    return $(this).text()    
}).get();
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hDLyk/1/)**

---

If you've multiple `tr`, you can loop through them:

```
var tdsArr = [];
$('table tr').each(function () {
    var tdArr = $(this).find('td:gt(0)').map(function () {
        return $(this).text()
    }).get();

    tdsArr.push(tdArr);
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hDLyk/2/)**

Comment: This will fail for more than one `tr` element. "first cell's values". `$('table tr').find('td:gt(0)')` will select all the `td` children of each `tr` except the first cells but your selector selects all the `td` children except the first one.

Comment: **@Felix**: Thank you for your code. Yet I got `1000,400,600` Please tell me that where the comma comes from? Moreover, I think that **undefined** may be right in cases that I have more than one `<tr>`...

Comment: **@Felix**: Please let me know how I can extend this with a selected cell to make it easier for the maintenance in the future, ex: third `<td>` element, fifth `<td>` element, or both third and fourth `<td>` element.